# 5V digital output to 24V

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier, logic-level, watchdog

I need to come up with something to convert a 5V digital output signal from a USB-1608G DAQ device with DIO to 24V digital output signal to reset the timer on a [watchdog](https://www.brentek.com/sites/default/files/uploads/attachments/products/P8E-WDT%20PLC%20Watchdog%20Timers.pdf).  The watchdog timer will only draw around 7.5mA, just requires around 24V pulse for at least 1mS to reset the WDI period.  Any ideas on how to go about this or directions to go in?

I am thinking I will use an enhancement nMOSFET, with a Vth of about 2.5V.  I am not sure what the best transistor would be to use and how to really configure the circuit so I can get that 24V output.

Comment: Can you share the datasheet of your watchdog device (or the device that contains the watchdog)?

Comment: https://www.brentek.com/sites/default/files/uploads/attachments/products/P8E-WDT%20PLC%20Watchdog%20Timers.pdf

Comment: Looks like it can accept 5V directly, no need to boost it to 24V

Comment: Yeah that's the problem.  I got it figuring that it can and I wouldn't have any issues. But when I test it, the timer will only reset a minimum of 17V.

Comment: @Dave, please include all relevant information in the question post. (Click "edit" to edit your post)

Comment: I see the 10 kohm typical resistance on pin 5 (is that the watchdog pin?). I assume that is to ground, but if it happens to be to 24V internally, you could use an open-drain output configuration. What voltage is the watchdog input when nothing is connected to it?

Comment: This device's data sheet explicitly says it is edge-triggered, your test with manually connecting a wire is not really driving it properly.  Try connecting it to an MCU pin set to toggle at an appropriate rate.

Answer (score 4):

If the question was "switch some load against a +24V PSU rail by a TTL gate", I'd say BS170, 2N7000TA or some such.

But, you probably need a narrow positive-going pulse.

With a single transistor, this would probably mean using a pull-up resistor, which would have to source current all across the 24 V in a "mostly ON" configuration... would generate a lot of waste heat. So, you need a switch to +24V. You need a pair of FET's (N and P polarity) and two resistors, or 1 resistor + 1 zener diode. Since the maximum gate voltage in MOSFETs is usually 20 Volts, or less, sometimes 12 Volts - in the P-FET you'd need to limit gate voltage. You could also achieve what you need with BJT's (1xNPN, 1xPNP) and about 3 resistors = invert the signal in a current-coupled fashion. Or a low-side 2N7000TA MOSFET + a high-side PNP BJT + two resistors to drive the high-side base.

Or, if this is in an industrial setup, you could use an off-the-shelf opto-coupler with TTL input and 24V output, in DIN-rail mounted package. Such as Weidmüller 8950700000 or 1126920000 (see pages 30 and 63 in [this catalogue](https://www.weidmuller.com/bausteine.net/dav/showdav.aspx?domid=1031&awpfad=http%3A%2F%2Fcmswebdav.weidmueller.de%2Fcms%2Fcom_Downloads%2FInformation_Material%2FProduct_Catalogues%2FTK4_2%2FEN%2F&rooturl=http%3A%2F%2Fcmswebdav.weidmueller.de%2Fcms%2Fcom_Downloads&awname=2545330000_CAT4-2_EN_WEB_Kapitel_A.pdf&type=downloadlist&addmin_fd=3&sp=Y&kompid=)). Sounds like a european device. Not sure what brand to recommend in other parts of the world - for instance GE doesn't ring a bell in Google...

Maybe also note that when you need to drive an opto-coupler device with a TTL gate, the [TTL logic family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400-series_integrated_circuits#BiCMOS) can make a difference in terms of delivered output current to drive the "primary LED" of the opto-coupler. Actually if this is an MCU or a computer with GPIO, the output's "source capability" can vary from pin to pin in the chip that's driving your 5V output (i.e. it's not down to its silicon family). Nowadays you'll probably be fine, but if the opto-coupler doesn't open, check the voltage across its input terminals with a digital volt-meter (these have megaohms of input impedance).

Answer (score 3):

Your device has a minimum high input voltage of just 2.0 V, so you can trigger it directly with your 5 V signal:

[image]

Comment: Yes which is the exact reason I got this watchdog. But when I tap the reset pin with a voltage source, the timer will not reset until about 17V.

Comment: Did you connect it to ground before you "tapped" it with the voltage supply? Because of the edge-triggered feature, you might need a clean 0-5 V transition to be sure to reset the WDT correctly.

Comment: Yes it is grounded and getting a clean 0-5V transition.

Comment: @Dave How does it behave if you run it off a lower voltage like 5-9V instead of 24V? Normally it's pretty clear if the Vih moves with the supply voltage but this datasheet is really brief. You could interpret the datsheet as it can accept between 2-30V as a HI. But it could also be interpreted that the logic HI threshold can vary between 2 and 30V which would mean that it changes with supply voltage.

Comment: I see your edit but yes, I did try that but like I said, even at the lowest supply voltage, the timer still cannot be reset with anything lower then 17V.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an open-collector buffer to drive a higher voltage from a 5 V digital signal. Like the 74LS07 hex buffer gate with open-collector. Data sheet says that it has a 30 V maximum output voltage.

Open collector means that the output NPN transistor is connected emitter to ground and the collector routed to the output pin. You can use that with a pull-up resistor and you can tie it to your 24 V line.

Be aware that not all 74LS* open collector devices can be used with up to 30 V. I see the TI data sheet for 74LS05 only supports up to 7V, but the '06 also does 30V. Both are hex-inverters. Look at all the open-collector items available at [Wikipedia's List of 7400-series integrated circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400-series_integrated_circuits)